# Vue.js - Input, v-model and computed property

Tags: vuejs2

I'm using `vue-2.4` and `element-ui 1.4.1`.

#### Situation

I have a basic `input` which is linked with `v-model` to a `computed property`. When `blur` I check if the value input is greater or lower than `min` and `max` and I do what I have to do ... Nothing fancy here.

#### Problem

The value displayed in the input does not always equal `enteredValue`

#### Steps to reproduce

1) Input `60`  --> Value displayed is the max so `50` and `enteredValue` is `50` (which is ok)

[image]

2) Click outside

3) Input `80`  --> Value displayed is `80` and `enteredValue` is `50`

[image]

#### Questions

How can I fix that so the value displayed is always the same as the `enteredValue` ?

Here is the minimal code to reproduce what I'm facing [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/0gxb0fw8/)

```
    <div id="app">
  The variable enteredValue is {{enteredValue}}
  <el-input v-model="measurementValueDisplay" @blur="formatInput($event)"></el-input>
</div>

var Main = {
  data() {
    return {
      enteredValue: '',
      max: 50,
      min: 10
    }
  },
  computed: {
      measurementValueDisplay: {
          get: function () {
              return this.enteredValue + ' inchs'
          },
          set: function (newValue) {
          }
     },
  },
  methods: {
      formatInput($event) {
         let inputValue = $event.currentTarget.value;
         if (inputValue > this.max) { this.enteredValue = this.max}
         else if (inputValue < this.min) { this.enteredValue = this.min}
         else this.enteredValue = inputValue
      }
  }
}
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

Comment: i've tried ton iput 80, as you told, but both shows 50, like code says do

Comment: First input `60` then click outside the box to trigger `blur` then re click in the box to put `80`

Comment: nshow 50 not 80

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Have you followed the steps? Don't you get the same thing as I posted?

Comment: Element UI does have an InputNumber with Min and Max values.

Comment: now, yes iv got same bug

Comment: @HarrieKiezebrink, I know they do, but it does not really help to solve this issue. The main thing here, I think, is the fact a computed property is used as a v-model

Comment: strange actuation because the value of measurementValueDisplay is setted ok

Comment: look at fiddle of my response it works, like u want

Comment: @Leo Oke, but using a computed property as an input-model feels like an anti-pattern to me. There is a reason why they are getters only by default. The main purpose is to cache the result of an operation and only recalculate when the underlying data property changes. Not to use that result as a reactive model. Besides, using the result of a computation as input makes validation much harder because of the string appending.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reading this [vuejs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html), will understand what happens

"**computed properties are cached based on their dependencies. A computed property will only re-evaluate when some of its dependencies have changed.**"

Changed some comportament of the code. Made run:
`computed()` method not works properly for update value in window. But if looks at console the value yes updated.
So, i remove computed (getter and setter), and put into data, without setter and getter[( i dont like this in javascript)](https://jsfiddle.net/0gxb0fw8/2/).

```js
var Main = {
  data() {
    return {
      measurementValueDisplay:'fff',
      enteredValue: '',
      max: 50,
      min: 10
    }
  },
  computed: {
      /*measurementValueDisplay: {
          get: function () {
              console.log('Computed was triggered so I assume enteredValue changed',this.enteredValue);
              return this.enteredValue + ' inchs'
          },
          set: function (newValue) {
          console.log('setter de qye', this.enteredValue);
          }
      },*/
  },
  methods: {
      formatInput($event) {
          this.enteredValue = 0;
          
          let inputValue = $event.currentTarget.value;
          console.log(inputValue);
          if (inputValue > this.max) { this.enteredValue = this.max}
          else if (inputValue < this.min) { this.enteredValue = this.min}
          else this.enteredValue = inputValue
          this.measurementValueDisplay = this.enteredValue + ' inchs'
          
          console.log(this.enteredValue, 'oioioioio0');
      }
   }
}
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

Comment: That is why I put `this.enteredValue = 0;` so enteredValue changes

Comment: @Leo yes but not works fine every time, not deteds window changed to update it

Comment: I wanted to used the `computed property` but I ended using it as a variable as you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the values used in the computed property was not updated with the validation capping at 50 (Was 50, is now updated to 50, no need to recalculate), therefore `v-model` did not update the input.

I've edited your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0gxb0fw8/4/) to use two computed properties:
One with an accessor to validate the entered value, one which returns the value with " inch" appended.

Here is the interesting part:

```js
    computed: {
          measurementValueDisplay: {
              get: function () {
                  return this.enteredValue
              },
              set: function (newValue) {
                 this.enteredValue = 0;
                 let inputValue = parseInt(newValue);
                 if(Number.isNaN(inputValue)){this.enteredValue = this.min}
                 else if (inputValue > this.max) { this.enteredValue = this.max}
                 else if (inputValue < this.min) { this.enteredValue = this.min}
                 else this.enteredValue = inputValue
              }
         },
         valueWithInch(){
            return this.enteredValue + " inch";
             }
      },
```

Comment: I like it but try to enter 500000 by keeping the 0 down. You would be able to get 50000 in the box and 50 as the value

Comment: You're right, this is the same problem as previously

I'll mess a bit with the code to find a better solution

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody still needs a hack for this one, you can use a value that will always change ( for example a **timestamp** )

```
var Main = {
  data() {
    return {
      enteredValue: '',
      max: 50,
      min: 10,
      now: 1 //line added
    }
  },
  computed: {
      measurementValueDisplay: {
          get: function () {
              return (this.now - this.now + 1 ) * this.enteredValue + ' inchs'; //line changed
          },
          set: function (newValue) {
              this.now = Date.now(); //line added
          }
     },
  },
  methods: {
      formatInput($event) {
         let inputValue = $event.currentTarget.value;
         if (inputValue > this.max) { this.enteredValue = this.max}
         else if (inputValue < this.min) { this.enteredValue = this.min}
         else this.enteredValue = inputValue
      }
  }
}
```